# What is the preferred way to run TensorFlow model inference on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-serving

I'd like to run model inference of a *Convolutional Neural Network* using `Tensorflow` on *Raspberry Pi* (RPI). Running the model in a Cloud **isn't** an option at the moment.

I imagine that there are two different ways how this can be done:

1) running `tensorflow` code directly on RPi. (it is now possible to directly `pip install tensorflow` on the RPi, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian).

2) running an instance of `ModelServer` using the `tensorflow serving`([official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic)).

Now, what I'd like to have is an app running on RPi that reads live sensor data (in my case *audio* from microphone) und runs a classification algorithm. I assume that querying a `ModelServer` would be the preferred option (and I won't even need to install `tensorflow` on RPi), but I could'n find any examples of this anywhere.

Has anybody have any experience with/knowledge of deploying tensorflow models on RPi?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that querying a ModelServer is the preferred option - you can discard the overhead from the TensorFlow installation on the RPi and utilize the computational resources of your backend machine (i.e. the GPU of whatever is hosting the ModelServer).

TensorFlow has a [RESTful API](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest), which is a lightweight method to perform remote inference from an IoT device like the RPi. You can build the REST-enabled ModelServer on your backend machine, then execute POST requests in real-time with the audio data from the RPi to the classification algorithm.

I couldn't find an example of a library that was designed for audio specifically, but an example of using this framework for images is my [TensorFlow Distributed Image Serving](https://github.com/tmlabonte/tendies) library. The overall concept will be pretty much the same for audio, but the pre- and post-processing will be a bit different depending on how exactly your audio is encoded.

Comment: Thanks, Tyler, for your helpful answer. My original intention was to perform the inference locally (i.e. run the ModelServer on RPi) and was wondering if that would be feasible?!? And my second thought is: why RESTful versus gRPC API?

Comment: Sure, you could perform inference on the RPi as long as the hardware is capable of running your model (e.g., if your model has millions of weights, then the RPi probably doesn't have enough RAM to store them).

Either REST or gRPC could be used - gRPC is more complex, but more efficient, and designed for "real" software, while REST is extremely simple and has low overhead. It's really up to preference for an RPi project, but I prefer REST for its ease-of-implementation.